# Why hasn't deep learning been used for word level alignment?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing

I've been exploring word-level alignments tools such as MGIZA and it seems to me that there hasn't been any new tool for this problem. Are neural networks not suitable to solve this problem or simply no interest in the area to build new tools?